# Facebook API : Publish to common page

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk

Is it possible that users of my app could publish posts to specified page (Page of the app or fan page) using Graph API ? Thanks.

Comment: I do not know what your app is doing. But with the right permissions you can do almost everything via Graph API. Just take a look into their documentation ;)

Comment: @Jurik , AFAIK you can't post to friends page, I can't find in documentation post on some page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Jurik pointed out in the comment, with the right permission, you can do almost everything via Graph API.

To publish a post on a page on behalf of a particular user, you can use the `/{page-id}/feed` endpoint. Take a look at the [Page API feed documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/feed/#publish). It says that using a valid [User Access Token](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/#usertokens) with `publish_actions` permission, you can publish new posts to the page **on behalf of that person**.

Following is the code snippet to do that using the Android SDK (Source: [Page API feed documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/feed/#publish)):

```
Bundle params = new Bundle();
params.putString("message", "This is a test message");
/* make the API call */
new Request(
    session,
    "/{page-id}/feed",
    params,
    HttpMethod.POST,
    new Request.Callback() {
        public void onCompleted(Response response) {
            /* handle the result */
        }
    }
).executeAsync();
```

Comment: @Rahil Arora - Is it possible to publish post in particular page of workplace from Android Application?